# How to make connection to the WSDL in SpringBoot application?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap

I am new to WSDL. I have a WSDL and need to make a connection to the endpoint using springBoot application and verify its working.

In my java class SoapClientConfig, I need contextPath and default Uri to set. With given WSDL, I am not sure what would be my contextPath and default Uri.
In the WSDL, I see following tag for address location.I am not sure, how to use this address in my Springboot application to make a connection to the API provided by same WSDL

```
       <wsdl:service name="PayServices">
             <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_PayServices" 
             binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_PayServices">
            <soap:address 
         location="https://test.testfw.ws/ts/gpcs/grsv/routerservice.svc"/>
           </wsdl:port>
     </wsdl:service>
```

One of the API operation outcome

```
<wsdl:operation name="PaymentOutcome">
            <soap:operation 

       soapAction="http://hide.net/services/atms/PayServices/PaymentOutcome" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:PayServices_RouterAddressing" part="ADDRESSING" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:PayServices_RouterSecurity" part="SECURITY" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:PayServices_Security" part="Security" use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
     <wsdl:fault name="SecurityFault">
        <soap:fault name="SecurityFault" use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:fault>
     <wsdl:fault name="RouterFault">
        <soap:fault name="RouterFault" use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

Java code for SOap client connection:

```
      @Configuration
      public class SoapClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public PaymentOutcomeClient paymentOutcomeClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        PaymentOutcomeClient client = new PaymentOutcomeClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
```

}

Comment: You want to call a SOAP API from Spring Boot and you have the WSDL document?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo Yes, I have added the SOAP Action above.